# How to remove the finish from a stainless steel/titanium ring?

Tags: metalworking, metal, jewelry, restoration

Any recommendations on how to remove the finish from this ring?  I'm thinking about trying to refinish it. It's a cheap ring but has sentimental value.  When I bought it, it was listed as stainless steel/titanium. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Maybe some twin pair wheels such as: https://www.gourdoupis.gr/cache/files/b994b192734861dbaa772f10a400ed9416a5bbbc.jpg

Comment: An alternate approach may me some sandpaper disks upon a dremel/rotary tool and then some buffing wheels. In my Kraussmann 7940 may be the case.

Comment: Just for clarity: you want to get rid of the black (or darker) finish? And what can you tell us about the nature of the darker part: does it chip off or wear off, for example?

Comment: Yes, remove the black  it doesn't chip off, and I'm not sure if it wears off or just tarnishes. I've never had any color come off on my fingers if that helps

Comment: Any suggestions on the grit I should be using for sandpaper?

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with a 0000 steel wool. If you don't get the results you want I'd go to a 000 and then a 00.

Sandpaper feels like a last resort. Sandpaper will start to bite into the metal and soften the features of the ring. If you have to go there I'd go as fine as possible to start, maybe 1000 and work my way to something rougher if fine does not work.

Comment: Great thanks for the advice

Comment: Try 400, if it does not remove dark finish ,use 320. You may want to polish with 600 if you don't want brush finish.